# error input string was not in a correct format c#

Tags: c#, excel

im working in a project where it has to import excel file and show its details in 3 different data grid .i have a button with codes here.

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(txtreg.Text) >  0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dgResult1.Columns.Count; i++)
                {

                    if (dgResult1.Columns[i].HeaderText == "REGHRS")
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dgResult1.Rows.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if          (Convert.ToInt32(dgResult1.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value.ToString()) >= 12)
                            {
                                dgResult1.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value = txtreg.Text;
                                dgResult2.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dgResult2.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value.ToString().Trim()) - Convert.ToInt32(txtreg.Text);
                                dgResult3.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and it throws an error with input string was not in a correct format .can somebody help me .thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is classic Debugging 101, and it's a good idea to learn it early in your career unless you're the coding Kwisatz Haderach, who can write bug-free code first time, every time :-)

Every time before you attempt a conversion with something like:

```
Convert.ToInt32(blah)
```

(I see four of those in your code, two on a single line), you should put in some temporary debug code (message box, or console writeline, or something) to find out what `blah` is actually set to. This should include the actual string, surrounded by `[]` characters, and the length of the string.

This will let you identify which string is failing the integer conversion. Once you've established that, the *next* step will be to work out why.

Answer (score 0):

### Handling Convert.ToInt32

your exception occurs by Convert.ToInt32(...) - you use it several times.. that means that in some point a string without a number passed to this function

my guess is that some field from the database contains null and represented by an empty string

althougth Convert.ToInt32 can deal with null values it fails on empty string values

a potential solution - use your own method:

```
int ConvertInt(string val)
{
    return (val.IsNullOrEmpty(val)) ? 0 : int.Parse(val); // Parse aimed to deal with strings only while Convert deals withe several types
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

        int regNumber = 0;
        bool regFlag = int.TryParse(txtreg.Text, regNumber)

        if(!regFlag)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Reg textbox doesn't have integer value");
           return;
        }

        if(regNumber <= 0)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Reg textbox has negative or 0 value");
           return;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < dgResult1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {

           if (dgResult1.Columns[i].HeaderText != "REGHRS")
                continue;


           for (int j = 0; j < dgResult1.Rows.Count; j++)
           {
               string regHrs = dgResult1.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value.ToString();
               int regValue = 0;

               bool regCheck = int.TryParse(regHrs, out regValue)

               if(!regCheck || reg < 12)
                   continue;

               dgResult1.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value = txtreg.Text;


               //till now both converts should be okay.
               dgResult2.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dgResult2.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value.ToString()) - Convert.ToInt32(txtreg.Text);

              dgResult3.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value = 0;

           }


       }

    }
```

The error is that you are converting somewhere wrong integer values. Also you have really bad structure of the code. You should avoid nested if. I wrote how the code should probably look like. Also why catch system exceptions, no user cares about them. You should show relevant text.

Comment: im still new to c#  .but thanks for your words i'll note that .
i'll just ask what's that **reg** in

    `if(!regCheck || reg < 12)`

Comment: @Tetsuya it is number which you trying to parse int.TryParse(txtreg.Text, regNumber)

Answer (score -1):

```
Below is my opinion 

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(txtreg.Text) >  0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dgResult1.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {

                        if (dgResult1.Columns[i].HeaderText == "REGHRS")
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < dgResult1.Rows.Count; j++)
                            {
                                if          (Convert.ToInt32(dgResult1.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value.ToString()) >= 12)
                                {
                                    dgResult1.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value = txtreg.Text;
                                    dgResult2.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dgResult2.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value.ToString().Trim()) - Convert.ToInt32(txtreg.Text);
                                    dgResult3.Rows[j].Cells["REGHRS"].Value = "0";//UpDate this

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```